# Linking to another rb file in Ruby Sinatra?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, sinatra

Let's say I have a table with a bunch of cities in `Cities.rb`. When I click on the city it will redirect me to a page that has some information on it in `Report.rb`. I was just wondering since it will make things a lot more organized. Is it possible to do this or do I need to do it all in `Cities.rb`?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some Minutes to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Unfortunately with the information given it's not clear what you already have, nor what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Apologies. Basically, can I have multiple rb files in one project that does a specific task or do I have to use routes for each specific task?

Comment: Sinatra doesn't care about Files, unlike PHP or similar. Routing happens programmatically: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html so i guess yes, you have to use routes for each specific task, but you can have them in different files.

Comment: For an example see this Blog post: http://blog.sourcing.io/structuring-sinatra